# How to show via induction the product rule for derivatives?

Tags: analysis

Hi I have to show by induction over the number $n$  the following product rule and I have no idea about it. Could someone provide me the proof and a nice explaination:

$$(f\cdot g)^{(n)} (x)= \sum_{k=0}^n\tbinom n k f^{(n-k)} (x) g^{(k)} (x)$$

The $h^{(k)}$ is the $k`th$ derivative of the function $h^{(0)} := h$

I have to use the in my induction proof rhe recursion formula (Pascal Triangle)

$\tbinom n k = \tbinom {n-1} k + \tbinom {n-1} {k-1}$

with $n>k>0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\left(f.g\right)^{\left(n\right)}$$ is the derivative of: $$\left(f.g\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}f^{\left(n-1-k\right)}.g^{\left(k\right)}$$

**Extension**:

Your inductionhypothese has the form: $$h\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}h_{k}\left(x\right)$$
This for $h\left(x\right):=\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{n-1}$,
$c_{k}:=\binom{n-1}{k}$ and $h_{k}\left(x\right):=f^{\left(n-1-k\right)}(x)g^{\left(k\right)}\left(x\right)$.

In general, if $h\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}h_{k}\left(x\right)$
where the $c_{k}$ are constants then $h'\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}h_{k}'\left(x\right)$.

Here $\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{n}=h'\left(x\right)$ (**the hint**) so: $$\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}h_{k}'\left(x\right)$$

Applying the productrule on: $$h_{k}\left(x\right)=f^{\left(n-1-k\right)}(x)g^{\left(k\right)}\left(x\right)$$
gives: $$h_{k}'\left(x\right)=f^{\left(n-k\right)}\left(x\right)g^{k}\left(x\right)+f^{\left(n-1-k\right)}(x)g^{\left(k+1\right)}\left(x\right)$$

Substitution of this results in: $$\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\left[f^{\left(n-k\right)}\left(x\right)g^{k}\left(x\right)+f^{\left(n-1-k\right)}(x)g^{\left(k+1\right)}\left(x\right)\right]$$
leading to:

$$\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}f^{\left(n-k\right)}\left(x\right)g^{k}\left(x\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}f^{\left(n-k\right)}(x)g^{\left(k\right)}\left(x\right)$$

Now it is time to use: $$\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\binom{n}{k}$$
resulting in: $$\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}f^{\left(n-k\right)}\left(x\right)g^{k}\left(x\right)$$

Comment: sorry, but its just too much. i´m having difficulties understanding this stuff. so the hint doesnt work, at least right now.

Comment: @Jacky Give it a second try. I expanded the hint.

Comment: sorry I still cant doit. I have no idea :(